# Ajax resquest responses always equal to zero in php mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to load some data from mysql to a div via ajax php. The id field which is auto increment is always equal to zero.

I have tried using get, post etc but none is working

```
<buttton onclick="openNav()" data-id="<?php echo $row['customer_id']?>"  data-target="#txtHint" id="getUser" ><?php echo $row['display_name'];?></button>    
    <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){

           $(document).on('click', '#getUser', function(e){

            e.preventDefault();

            var uid = $(this).data("customer_id");   // it will get id of clicked row

            $('#txtHint').html(''); // leave it blank before ajax call
            $('#mySidenav').show();      // load ajax loader

            $.ajax({
              url: 'getCustomerDetails.php',
              type: 'GET',
              data: 'customer_id='+uid,
              dataType: 'html'
            })
            .done(function(data){
              console.log(data);  
              $('#txtHint').html('');    
              $('#txtHint').html(data); // load response 
              $('#modal-loader').hide();      // hide ajax loader 
            })
            .fail(function(){
              $('#txtHint').html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i> Something went wrong, Please try again...');
              $('#modal-loader').hide();
            });

          });

         });

        </script>


                <?php

        include_once('../../config/dbconfig.php');


            if (isset($_REQUEST['customer_id'])) {

                $id = intval($_REQUEST['customer_id']);
                $query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer_id=:id";
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare( $query );
                $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
                $row=$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


                ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                    <div class="col-md-4" >
                        <?php echo $row['first_name'];?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <?php echo $id;?><br/>


        <?php
        }

        ?>
```

The result is not echoing the first_name because the $id is always 0. I want to get the individual $id(auto_increment) when is done it should display user record
I don't know if the data-id is not working correctly or not

Answer (score 2):

you must replace this line:

```
var uid = $(this).data("customer_id")
```

by this line:

```
var uid = $(this).data("id")
```

or

```
var uid = $(this).attr("data-id")
```